# Не включается эмулятор андроида в Android studio

Tags: android-studio, эмулятор

Искала, но не нашла подобное, именно сам "смартфон" не включается. То есть я создаю в AVD Manager устройство, потом нажимаю Run app, выбираю нужное мне устройство, оно появляется, но не функционирует. чёрный экран. ну то есть как выключенный смартфон. ни на какие кнопки сбоку не реагирует.[image: черный экран]

Comment: Так со всеми эмуляторами? Имеется в виду архитектура 86/64. Ещё можно `Genymotion` вместо гуглового попробовать

Comment: Пока не пробовала, но разобралась вроде с имеющимся. спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Можете отписать в чем причина была? такая же проблема. оперативы точно хватает.

Answer (score 3):

Методом проб и ошибок вышло вот так - убрала галочку с Enable ADB Integration (Tools->Android) и эмулятор загрузился. Галочку потом вернула, всё работает

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам не хватает оперативной памяти для загрузки эмулятора, уменьшите в менеджере память устройства, мне помогало.

Comment: спасибо, если ещё возникнет  такое, попробую зайти с этой стороны)

Answer (score 1):

У меня такая же проблема была. Убрать\вернуть галочку не помогло, с оперативкой тоже было все нормально.

**Решил так:** склонировал эмулятор (Duplicate) и клон нормально запустился. Старый багнутый удалил просто.

PS: при клонировании все данные\приложения перенеслись без потерь.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая ситуация - выключил смартфон в эмуляторе, а потом он не включался. Решение: открыл диспетчер задач, а там какой-то процесс (qemu-system-x86_64) жрет много ресурсов я его снял. Заново запустил андройд студио, эмулятор заработал нормально. Оказалось этот процесс и был зависший эмулятор.